# Collapse menu when open another BUTTON

Tags: javascript

I have a menu mobile that use accordion method, but when i open a button, they just close when click in the same button again, but i want to close always then open a new button.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("sidr-class-accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Compra Sortida</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>
    <a href="produtos/index/categoria/venda-unitaria/subcategoria/camisetas-algodao">Camisetas Algodão</a>
  </p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Compra Unitária</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>
    <a href="produtos/index/categoria/venda-unitaria/subcategoria/camisetas-venda">Camisetas Algodão</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no `.sidr-class-accordion` on your HTML

Comment: Sure, its because not is my complete code, this html code is inside an <aside> and the div contents change the name to "sidr-class"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue appears to be that the `sidr-class-accordion` class is not defined in your HTML.

Another approach to scripting this accordian menu (that allows you to retain the current HTML structure) would be as follows:

```js
/* Store list of accordion buttons and panels for later use */
const buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".accordion"));
const panels = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".panel"));

/* Iterate each accordion button where click event on each will be defined  */
for (const button of buttons) {

  button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

    /* Derive index of clicked button based on poisiton in the buttons array */
    const index = buttons.indexOf(button);

    for (const panel of panels) {
      if (panel === panels[index]) {

        /* If panel matches panel of clicked button then toggle vibility */
        panel.classList.toggle("visible");
      } else {

        /* Otherwise hide the panel */
        panel.classList.remove("visible");
      }
    }

  });
}
```

```css
.panel {
  display:none;
}

.visible {
  display:block;
}

button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Compra Sortida 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>
    <a href="produtos/index/categoria/venda-unitaria/subcategoria/camisetas-algodao">Camisetas Algodão 1</a>
  </p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Compra Unitária 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>
    <a href="produtos/index/categoria/venda-unitaria/subcategoria/camisetas-venda">Camisetas Algodão 2</a>
  </p>
</div>
```